# How to get a specific value from a file to a JSP page?

Tags: java, jsp

I am having file which contains version number. For Example

```
foo.cf
something
somevalue
somevalue
........
.......
version = "7.1"
........
.........
```

I want to get the value 7.1(It can be anything) from the file foo.cf into my JSP page. 
Can anybody help me how to do it
I know how to read a file but dont know how to get the specific value. This is how I read the file from JSP. If my code is wrong please correct me

```
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("foo.cf"));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        while((line = reader.readLine())!= null){

        }
```

Comment: You need to use Regular Expression

Comment: can you give a example

Comment: see my answer to use regular expressionl.

Answer (score 0):

May be you could try this (not tested):

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("foo.cf"));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while((line = reader.readLine())!= null){
    if(line.startsWith("version")
    {
        //will give "7.1":
        String version = line.substring(line.indexOf("="),
            line.length());
        // use this instead of the line above to get 7.1:
        // String version = line.substring(line.indexOf("="),
            line.length()).replaceAll("\"","").trim();
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the version string line has more than one "="   It will fail.

Comment: The code is based upon the sample string provided by OP. Also, it is less likely for a version string to contain two "=".

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can use Regular Expression.

This is an example. You will need to modify this to your requirement.

```
package snippet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;



public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "foo.cf something somevalue somevalue ........ ....... version = \" 7.1 \" ........ .........";

        String exp = ".*version\\s*=\\s*\"([^\"]+)";
        System.out.println(runSubRegex(exp, test));

    }

    private static String runSubRegex(String regex, String tag) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(tag);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            return matcher.group(1);
        }
        return null;

    }

}
```

This will print any value in between `version=" "` in this case 7.1 regardless of spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the file in Jsp is not good practice

Please do this in Servlet's doPost() or doGet() method

```
 String version ="";
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("foo.cf"));
 String line;
 while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
         line = line.trim();
         if(line.startsWith("version")){
              String[] strings = line.split("=");
              version = strings[1];
               break;
          }
 }
 br.close();
```

Add this within your request object inside the servlet

```
 request.setAttribute("version",version);
```

Add the following in your jsp page

```
   <% String version = (String)request.getAttribute("version");%>
```

Comment: I am not using servlet can i access it directly from JSp

Answer (score -1):

If your file is kind of below format:

```
name=foo.cf
xyz=abc
xyz1=abc1
version=7.1
```

I mean key=value kind of content. Then the below code is a sophisticated way of retrieving the version.

```
            File file = new File("foo.cf");
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            HashMap<String, String> defPropMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            try {
                inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream);
                while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                    String[] columns = scanner.nextLine().split("=");
                    if(columns.length == 2)
                        defPropMap.put(columns[0].trim(), columns[1].trim());
                    else
                        defPropMap.put(columns[0].trim(), null);
                }

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                logger.warn("Caught FileNotFoundException", e);

            }
            finally{
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    logger.warn("Caught IOException", e);

                }
            }
```

otherswise line by line read.